# Git origin resetting itself

Tags: git

I have two repositories that seem to have a linked origin.

If I navigate to my local repository and change the origin using

```
git remote set-url origin <myURL>
```

it resets the origin in my other repository as well.

Is there a way to unlink these repositories?
So far I have found three repositories that have been linked.
I have quite a few, and I haven't checked them all though.

Comment: Are those repositories you mention "nested", by any chance? Do you have one (or more) repos within another?

Comment: No, they are separate repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Each git repository has its own `remote`.

If you have updated one repo and all of the others were updated as well looks like you are using `worktree` and not a `clone`

In order to verify that you are using `worktree` in your repositories type:

```
git worktree list
```

If you have more than one repository then updating one will update them all.
If you dont see more than one so check out each repo for its remote url :

```
git remote --vv
```

Comment: I tried to see if it is a worktree. I only see /GitHub  b16fe42 [master] I'm not seeing a repository at all. I feel I'm not doing it right.